# TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'begin' has DataType float32 not in list of allowed values: int32, int64

Tags: tensorflow

when i am cropping image got by tensorflow object detection API but getting this error

```
TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'begin' has DataType float32 not in list of allowed values: int32, int64
```

I am using `cropped_image= tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(image_np, int(yminn), int(xminn), int(ymaxx-yminn), int(xmaxx-xminn))`

Please Help

Comment: Like this it is hard to determine where your problem is. If you have some code, post it here so people can take a look at it and then explain to you where your problem comes from. Your error suggests that you are trying to pass a value of the wrong type. Please edit your question and if you add code, please read this first: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had this exact problem yesterday. This seems to have started as i had installed tensorflow and anaconda together on windows seperately initially. But at one point i tried again install tensorflow using conda create in anaconda command prompt. If you want to save time, just go ahead uninstall and re-install tensorflow, conda (if installed), pythong